# Pad Left Not Working on Mobile

Tags: css

the pad left is not working for my mobile code. I'm trying to pad the paragraph text with the article div. It seems to be working fine on desktop resolution. Any clue? Thanks!

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  article {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
  }
  article h2 {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    font-size: 30px;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  article p {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h2><em> "Fanwood Text is a revival of Fairfield. Duh."</em></h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

</article>
```

Comment: You're simply not hitting the Media breakpoint, try a higher value, just to see it working

Comment: I tried this but it's not working. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be working based off of what i see [in this JSFiddle -here.](http://jsfiddle.net/wurt76gp/) I added background yellow to watch the change happen when scaling browser window. Also i doubled the padding left to 20px for a better visualization of the change working withing the media query

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {

article {
width: 100%;
margin: auto;

}

article h2 {
width: 100%;
margin: 10px;
text-align: left;
line-height: 1.4em;
font-size: 30px;
z-index: -1;
opacity: 1;
padding: 10px;

}

article p {

width: 100%;
margin: auto;
padding-left: 20px;
background: yellow;

}
}
```

Comment: Weird, it's still not working for me. Screenshot: https://postimg.cc/image/fori7jwjf/

Comment: did you scale the jSFiddle window down at all? when the snippet is first ran, the display window is bigger than the 400px the media query is looking for. Scale the window down to 400px or less and the background color changes as well as the padding-left see here: https://postimg.cc/image/kxczgm10h/

Comment: Ah yes I see. It's still not working in Dreamweaver. I wonder if I have a conflicting call out. Thanks for your help.